# Unzip multiple zip folders with the original name

Tags: powershell

I am new at powershell and stuck at making code as I have around 20 zip folders located at `D:\Input`. I want to unzip all the folders at `D:\Output` with the original name of zip folder but with the following requirement that is for example I have zip folder located at D:\Input with the name "`ET_NM.TEST_DATA_2.ET_ID.84.C_ID.4016.Part.1.20190502.0826`" and it contains the following folder "`1ac7b-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33cbe7`".

So when I unzip then I want the following folder at D:\Output "`1ac7b-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33cbe7`". After that script will rename this folder "`1ac7b-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33cbe7`" to the original zip folder that is "`ET_NM.TEST_DATA_2.ET_ID.84.C_ID.4016.Part.1.20190502.0826`". I have to the same step to 20 zip folders so I think for loop will be preferable. Can anyone please help me in this script

```
$ZipFilesPath = "D:\Input"
$UnzipPath = "D:\Output"

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($UnzipPath)

$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP

$progress = 1
foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Unzipping to $($UnzipPath)" -PercentComplete (($progress / ($ZipFiles.Count + 1)) * 100) -CurrentOperation $ZipFile.FullName -Status "File $($Progress) of $($ZipFiles.Count)"
    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)


    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)
    $progress++
    $a= $ZipFile.Name
    Write-Host $a
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please guide as I am badly stuck here

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code in a [mcve].

Comment: @LotPings I have attempted this. Let me add here my script

Comment: Dear @LotPings I have attached my script where I successfully unzip all the folders and save the name of zip file in variable but unable to find a solution to rename this  unzip folder to the name of the original zip folder which in this case I stored in $a. Kindly guide me

Comment: Your wording is unclear to me. `After that script will rename this folder` is what you ***want*** the script to do?

Comment: Yes I want to rename the unzipped folders with the name of original zipped folders at the end . This is the point where I am stuck. @LotPings kindly guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's unclear upfront what the zip file contains, I suggest to

- first create a folder in `D:\Output` with the zip files BaseName and unzip there.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\23\SO_56279162.ps1
$ZipFilesPath =  "D:\Input"  # 'A:\Input'  #
$UnzipBase    =  "D:\Output" # 'A:\Output' #

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application

$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP

$progress = 1
foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Unzipping to $($UnzipPath)" `
      -PercentComplete (($progress / ($ZipFiles.Count + 1)) * 100) `
      -CurrentOperation $ZipFile.FullName `
      -Status "File $($Progress) of $($ZipFiles.Count)"

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)

    $UnzipPath = Join-Path $UnzipBase $ZipFile.BaseName
    New-Item $UnzipPath -ItemType Directory | Out-NUll
    $Location = $Shell.NameSpace($UnzipPath)

    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)
    $progress++
}
```

Sample tree (on my RamDrisk A:)

```
> tree /F A:\
A:\
├───input
│       ET_NM.TEST_DATA_2.ET_ID.84.C_ID.4016.Part.1.20190502.0826.zip
│
└───Output
    └───ET_NM.TEST_DATA_2.ET_ID.84.C_ID.4016.Part.1.20190502.0826
        └───1ac7b-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33cbe7
                test.txt
```

Comment: Dear @LotPings.  Actually I want first unzip the zip folder and then replace unzip folder with zip folder that is base name . At the first step script unzip this folder "ET_NM.TEST_DATA_2.ET_ID.84.C_ID.4016.Part.1.20190502.0826" and now at the output we have unzipped folder that is "1ac7b-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33cbe7" and then at the second just name of this folder that is "1ac7b-2d62-403c-8394-5bd33cbe7" have to be replaced with the original folder name "ET_NM.TEST_DATA_2.ET_ID.84.C_ID.4016.Part.1.20190502.0826". Actually this is the requirement . Kindly guide me on this and thanks for help

Comment: You failed to give a detailed example. Upfront you do not know what a zip file contains. There might be files directly in the zip or folders in there might be interfering with folders already present. With my approach you still can iterate subfolders and move the contents one level up to achieve what you want.